# View PDF document inside the same WPF windows

Tags: wpf, pdf, browser

I need to view a pdf document inside a WPfWindows. I'm using a WebBrowser for it, and when i run the app in a WinXP 32Bits machine the document appear inside the WPFWindow, but when i run it in WinVista 64bit it open in a new browser(it look like if the browser download the pdf document). I'm working with VS2008. Then for testing purpose I also create a new WPF app in VS2010 with WinVista 64Bits and there the pdf document open inside the WpfWindows as i want, but i can't work with VS2010 in this project. Please, somebody knows why it happen and how I can fixed,
Thanks in advance.

I am using Adobe Acrobat 8 32bit, VS2008 32bits, IExplorer 8.

Pd: Please, forgive any spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered your question when you said "I am using Adobe Acrobat 8 32bit, VS2008 32bits, IExplorer 8".

In a 64 bit OS, your WPF application will be run as a 64 bit application, hence it will be linked to Internet Explorer 64 bit and Acrobat Reader will not run inside the browser. In order to solve your problem you can force your application to be built as 32 bit (x86) instead of AnyCPU.

[image]